# why we write media queries like that in sass?

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

I trying to understand the logic behind media queries in sass.

For example, if I want to set media queries for my container in css in will be:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 37em){
.container{
      some code
  }
}
```

But in sass it will be:

```
.container {
  @media only screen and (max-width: $bp-medium){
    some code
  }
}
```

As you can see it the upset!

how the sass look after it compiled?

Comment: If you set `$bp-medium` variable in sass to be `37em`, the compiled css will look same as in your first example.

Comment: That's what making Sass powerful,
seperate the concerne and that will help in future mintanance.

Comment: How exactly? it seems that the css way much more organized

Comment: The advantage of the SASS way only becomes clear when applied in deeply nested rules.

Answer (score 0):

In sass you can e.g. set standard values - just like in your example `$bp-medium`. If you set this value to `37em`, it will behave similar to your css example.

By the way, you can just as well use the css way for sass. Wouldn't recommend though, since this is what sass makes powerful.

Answer (score 0):

By moving the media query inside a selector, you are organising all styles relevant to a component in the same place. When you choose to do it the CSS way, you'll organise the styles based on the media queries. This will give you a bad overview of what the component would look like in big projects and large files.